# Google geocoding API - Search on specific fields

Tags: java, google-maps, geocoding

I know `Google` provides various `component types` to search upon, apart from the list shown below.

```
administrative_area_level_1
administrative_area_level_2
locality
sublocality
postalcode
```

suppose user searches for something. Is it possible to restrict the user search for only above mentioned parameters instead of all.

How can I make my URL then.

`Country` I know I can restrict. this is the URL I'm forming and hitting,

**But I want to restrict the search (`uttam+nagar`) on above parameters only.**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyDnLJxpRbJpS2NEbiOf-FQ-K-YmQZ8V-yw&components=country%3AIN&address=uttam+nagar
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand your needs, I think you can use [Component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering)

> You can also set the Geocoding Service to return address results restricted to a specific area. Specify the restriction by using the componentRestrictions parameter. A filter consists of one or more of: route, locality, administrativeArea, postalCode or country. Only results matching all the filters will be returned. Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and partial matching as other geocoding requests.

Comment: The one you are talking about is restricting area statically , like search with India, then within Delhi etc.. but i want match teh search with what user is searching.